# CIColorPosterize in iOS

Tags: iphone, ios, cocoa-touch, uiimageview, core-image

Is CIColorPosterize available in iOS ? I am using following code for core image filter but the filter value is always 0. Filter for sepia is working fine . I just wanted to know that if CIColorPosterize is available in iOS and if yes what is the problem in my code.An help is appreciated.

-(void)imageDraw{

```
UIImage *image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"cat2.jpg"];

CIImage *beginImage = [CIImage imageWithCGImage:[image CGImage]];
CIContext *context = [CIContext contextWithOptions:nil];
 CIFilter* posterize = [CIFilter filterWithName:@"CIColorPosterize"];
[posterize setDefaults];
[posterize setValue:[NSNumber numberWithDouble:8.0] forKey:@"inputLevels"];
[posterize setValue:beginImage forKey:@"inputImage"];


CIImage *outputImage = [posterize outputImage];

CGImageRef cgimg = [context createCGImage:outputImage fromRect:[outputImage extent]];
UIImage *newImg = [UIImage imageWithCGImage:cgimg];


imgVIew.image = newImg;
 ALAssetsLibrary *library = [[ALAssetsLibrary alloc] init];  

[library writeImageToSavedPhotosAlbum:[newImg CGImage] orientation:(ALAssetOrientation)           [newImg imageOrientation] completionBlock:^(NSURL *assetURL, NSError *error){  
    if (error) {  
        NSLog(@"error");  
    } else {  
        NSLog(@"url %@", assetURL);  
    }  
}];  

CGImageRelease(cgimg);
}
```

Comment: If you do want a GPU-accelerated posterize implementation, I have one here: https://github.com/BradLarson/GPUImage

Answer (score 0, accepted):

***Update***

[CIColorPosterize is now available for iOS 6](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/GraphicsImaging/Reference/CoreImageFilterReference/Reference/reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/filter/ci/CIColorPosterize)

```
-(void)logAllFilters {
    NSArray *properties = [CIFilter filterNamesInCategory:
      kCICategoryBuiltIn];
    NSLog(@"%@", properties);
    for (NSString *filterName in properties) {
        CIFilter *fltr = [CIFilter filterWithName:filterName];
        NSLog(@"%@", [fltr attributes]);
    }
}
```

Comment: CIColorPosterize is now available in iOS 6.

Answer (score 0):

On [this page](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#DOCUMENTATION/GraphicsImaging/Reference/CoreImageFilterReference/Reference/reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40004346), they list all the `CIFilters`, and they list which version of MacOS and iOS each is available on, and `CIColorPosterize` is not listed as being available on iOS. You could also try calling `[+CIFilter filterNamesInCategory:]` with the category `CICategoryColorEffect` and see if you get back `CIColorPosterize` in the list.